# Android Multiple Handlers Design

Tags: android, android-activity, handler

This question is related to an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829595/android-2-1-muliple-handlers-in-a-single-activity) I asked. I though I'll ask a new question instead of replying back to the other question.

> "I've more than one Handlers in an Activity." Why? If you do not want a complicated `handleMessage()` method, then use `post()` (on `Handler` or `View`) to break the logic up into individual `Runnables`. Multiple `Handlers` makes me nervous. — CommonsWare

I'm new to Android. My question is - is having multiple handlers in a single activity a bad design?

Here is the sketch of my current implementation.

I've a `mapActivity` that creates a data thread (a UDP socket that listens for data). My first handler is responsible for sending data from the data thread to the activity.

On the map I've a bunch of "dynamic" markers that are `refreshed` frequently. Some of these markers are video markers i.e., if the user clicks a video marker, I add a  `ViewView` that extends a `android.opengl.GLSurfaceView` to my map activity and display video on this new vide. I use my second handler to send information about the marker that the user tapped on `ItemizedOverlay` `onTap(int index)` method.

The user can close the video view by tapping on the video view. I use my third handler for this.

I would appreciate if people can tell me what's wrong with this approach and suggest better ways to implement this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in my previous comment, I would not use multiple Handler objects for that.

With respect to the UDP socket thread, you can either stick with your existing `Handler`, or use `post()` on your `MapView` to post a `Runnable` to the main application thread, or use `runOnUiThread()` on your `MapActivity`.

With respect to your "second handler to send information about the marker that the user tapped on ItemizedOverlay onTap(int index) method", `onTap()` will be called on the main application thread, and so you do not need to use a `Handler`. The same is true for your third `Handler`.

Comment: But...aside from the fact that it is a bad desing, what happens if you have multiple handlers? They both receive all the messages, only the first declared, only the second? I guess both, but if you can give me an answer without me having to code it, I'd be happy!

Comment: @type-a1pha: None of the above. Part of the protocol for sending a `Message` indicates which `Handler` is to be the recipient of the message. Hence, there is never a question as to which `Handler` gets the message, regardless of the number of `Handler` objects that may be outstanding.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please help me here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35443200/3593066 Thanks.