# Implications of creating a new Handler in the main thread

Tags: android, handler

I am a beginner in the android world and I struggle at the moment with some concepts. One of them is the Handler object. I have reaserched this subject but I still don't have a full understanding of the subject. I might have some concepts confused.
Here is a simple app I wrote that shows a progress bar on the screen.

```
    package com.example.mjack.progressbarthread;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Handler mHandler;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    TextView mTextView;
    Thread myThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                mProgressBar.setProgress(msg.arg1);
                mTextView.setText("Progress....   " + (msg.arg1 +1) + " %");
                if (msg.arg1 == 99)  {

                    mTextView.setText("Done!!!");
                }

            }
        };
        myThread = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        myThread.start();

    }


    class MyRunnable implements Runnable {


        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {

                Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                message.arg1 = i;
                mHandler.sendMessage(message);
                try {
                    myThread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        }
    }
```

From what I understand so far (and please correct me if I'm wrong):
1.The main thread already has a Looper and Handler attached to it to be able to perform queued tasks (unlike new threads in which i have to prepare() a Looper and instantiate a Handler).
2.Only one Handler can be attached at a specific time to a thread (until it is replaced by a newly instantiated Handler object).

My question is: if I create a new Handler in the main thread and it is now attached to the thread and handles the messages from my background thread (through the overridden handleMessage method), what happens if I click on a button in that activity for example (if I had a button that does something in my layout) while the Handler is still in the process of handling messages from the background thread? what object handles the button click event (doesn't it have to go through a Handler considering there could be multiple events?)

I hope I have been clear enough. Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think only one Handler can be 'attached' to a thread (well, Looper) at a time?  Also, if you have a Handler running on the application's main looper that does some long running processing, it'll block the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you Submersed. This was my understanding, note that I stated "please correct me if I'm wrong". If using a Handler blocks the UI thread, then why use it at all to communicate between a background thread and the UI thread? and also please suggest a 'better' word for 'attached'. Thank you

Comment: The motivation for using a background thread is if the code execution is long running enough to be blocking.  This would generally include things like I/O operations, bitmap loading/manipulation, network operations, etc -- For example, you want the actual execution of network operation or data retrieval (long running) to be performed on a background thread so the main thread can continue executing it's message queue during your network op, and then when you have your response, you would post results from your background thread to the UI thread so you can update your UI.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829595/android-2-1-muliple-handlers-in-a-single-activity), it looks like each handler will receive the message in the order that you instantiate them.

Comment: Thank you chris. I have already seen that question and the answer there didn't help me understand it better. I don't understand what happens if I add more code after attaching my new Handler (that doesn't have to do with the background thread). Now that that Handler is attached to the main thread, who will process queued tasks. That question page you posted tells me that if I instantiate another Handler before that extra code it will now handle all future tasks but it still doesn't answer my question - what happens while the Handler i created to handle a background thread is still attached.